# Unable to install AD-Domain-services on VM

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, rdp

I trying to build out a SharePoint 2016 Dev/test farm in Azure using PowerShell, starting with a DS server

Anyway, I have created my VM, created virtual network, public IP, NIC etc 
DS VM is configured for RDP

I am getting stuck on installing the AD Domain Services
`Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools`

> Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
>   ------- -------------- ---------      --------------
>   False   Maybe          Failed         {}
>   Install-WindowsFeature : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-WindowsFeature -ComputerName adVm AD-Domain-Services -Include ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (Microsoft.Manag...rDetailsHandle):CimException) [Install-WindowsFeature],
>      Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnSupportedTargetDevice,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureComman
>      d

- I have installed [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)
- Started WInRM
- `Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value myVM`
- Q: Should I try to use the [AD DS Deployment Commandlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974719%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) directly from my win10 client

Comment: not a stack overflow question, superuser or server fault

Comment: This is a name resolution problem.  "The WinRM client cannot process the request *because the server name cannot be resolved.*"

Comment: Yes, agree. Assuming it's not the age old host file edit, I will try and find out how I can overcome this